# Error while trying to compile Cython output with GCC

Tags: python, gcc, cython

I'm trying to compile a Cython3 file into an executable using GCC.
For the moment I'm still stuck with a simple "hello world" :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("Hello World !")
```

Here is the command I've tried to execute in order to compile this simple program :

```
cython3 test.pyx
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.4 test.c
```

The first command run correctly, but here is what I get when I type the second one :

```
cython.c:422:14: error: conflicting types for ‘PyTypeObject’
 typedef void PyTypeObject;
              ^
In file included from /usr/include/python3.4/pytime.h:6:0,
                 from /usr/include/python3.4/Python.h:65,
                 from cython.c:16:
/usr/include/python3.4/object.h:422:3: note: previous declaration of ‘PyTypeObject’ was here
 } PyTypeObject;
   ^
cython.c: In function ‘__Pyx_PyObject_GetAttrStr’:
cython.c:488:18: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
     if (likely(tp->tp_getattro))
                  ^
cython.c:399:43: note: in definition of macro ‘likely’
   #define likely(x)   __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
                                           ^
cython.c:488:18: error: request for member ‘tp_getattro’ in something not a structure or union
     if (likely(tp->tp_getattro))
                  ^
cython.c:399:43: note: in definition of macro ‘likely’
   #define likely(x)   __builtin_expect(!!(x), 1)
                                           ^
cython.c:489:18: warning: dereferencing ‘void *’ pointer
         return tp->tp_getattro(obj, attr_name);
                  ^
cython.c:489:18: error: request for member ‘tp_getattro’ in something not a structure or union
```

I'm currently running on Debian testing, and therefore I have the following versions of Python and Cython :

```
Python: 3.4.2-2
Cython: 0.21.1-1
```

Comment: I deleted my answer because it doesn't work for you. In my PC I solved the problem using setup.py, so I cannot really track the problem anymore to try to help with it. Sorry if I wasted your time.

Comment: There is no wasted time, every constructive answer is a new step to the solution. Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved using the following commands :

```
cython3 test.pyx
gcc -I/usr/include/python3.4m test.c -lpython3.4m
```

Answer (score 0):

I doubt your answer solves the problem.

Your original problem was, that the extension was called `cython.pyx` (taking into account [this post](https://www.debian-fr.org/t/cython-probleme-a-la-compilation/65404)).

However, it is not allowed to name your cython-module "cython" because it is a special name for Cython and leads to a generated c-file which cannot be compiled (for whatever reason spurious `typedef void PyTypeObject;` is inserted). Unluckily cython doesn't report an error for this case.

Renaming the pyx-file/extension from `cython.pyx` to `test.pyx` solved the issue.